# How to print the contents of a unsigned char array within a struct?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have the following struct that contains an unsigned char array and I don't know how to print the contents of the array within the struct in the following context.

The char array is null terminated.

```
typedef data_type
{
  int a;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char c[33];
} DATA_TYPE, *DATA;
```

I create an instance of the struct

```
DATA data;
data = (DATA) malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE);

/* some code where I populate its values... */

printf("data->a = %d", data->a);
printf("data->b = %u", data->b);
printf("data->c = NOT SURE HOW TO PRINT THIS PART");
```

Comment: That would be `printf("data->c = %s", data->c);`

Comment: `printf("data->c = %s", data->c)`

Comment: Please show how you populate the array. Is it a null terminated string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a `NUL` (`'\0'`) terminated string, you can use what was suggested in the comments (`printf("data->c = %s", data->c);`).  If not, you can use a loop to print the entire array.  For example:

```
printf("data->c = ");
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(data->c); i++)
    printf("%u ", data->c[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@Fiddling Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62959245/2410359) good answer:

If `data->c` lacks a *null character*, all the array can be printed as text with by using a *precision*.  It limits output to `(int) sizeof data->c`, the size of the array.  Note the precision is an `int` argument and `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, hence the cast below.

```
printf("%.*s\n", (int) sizeof data->c, data->c);
```

With a *null character* in `data->c[]`, the above acts like `"%s\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Does `c` contain a NUL terminated C string? If so, use `%s`.

Otherwise, you need to write your own display function iterating over the `c` array in some way.

Personally, I would reuse one of the dozen or so implementations of a `void hexdump(const void *buf, const size_t size)` or similar function I have written over the last twenty years.

Some C standard libraries also allow hooking your own format character into the `*printf` function, but that probably is not very portable.